# How do I show multiple lines on the same graph in tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have my graph set up, so that a sum total is in rows, and month is in columns. I would like to see the last three years as separately colored bars or lines in the same graph. I created sets for 2014,2015, and 2016, but for some reason can not get it to do what I have described above.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to create a calculated field that "groups" those 3 years into one value/label, then use that in the colors card.

The calculated field may look something like:

`IF [YearField] >= 2014 AND [YearField] <= 2016 THEN 'Last 3 Years' ELSE STR([YearField]) END`